# Why is it called a skew field?

Tags: field-theory, terminology

Like, why is the word "skew" used.  (I know what they are & stuff... this is an etymology question.)

Answer (score 4):

In 1940, Nathan Jacobson wrote the paper "The Fundamental Theorem of the Galois Theory for Quasi-Fields" in *Annals of Mathematics* **41** (1940), 1-7.  The review of this paper on MathSciNet begins

> Let $P$ be a quasi-field (that is, non-commutative field or division-ring)

That review doesn't use the term "skew field".  There is one earlier review with the word "quasi-field" from 1939 and an unreviewed PhD thesis *Theory of algebras over a quasi-field* by Echo Dolores Pepper at the University of Chicago in 1925.

The earliest review mentioning "skew field" is for the book *Finite Geometrical Systems* by Levi in 1942.

The term "quasi-field" is no longer used for division rings, but there was a time when "skew field" and "quasi-field" were both in use. I suspect "skew" just had the same intended meaning as "quasi", namely a skew-object is something sort of like the actual object, but different in some way. Look up the terms skew-symmetric and quasigroup, for example.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think it means anything much deeper than "$ab$ isn't equal to $ba$, so they're... y'know... skew from each other," something like that.

Comment: Worth adding that *skew* is a lot more specific than *quasi-* — mathematically, it’s always something to do with antisymmetry or anticommutativity, fitting the real-world image of asymmetry/irregularity that its ordinary meaning evokes.  Which mathematical sense of *skew* came first — *skew-symmetric*, *skew-field*, or something else?  Presumably, the later ones were named by analogy with the earlier, so (coming back to the question) *skew fields* may have been named with *skew-symmetric* in mind.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine it would be good to point out how a division ring’s multiplication resembles something that is  “anti-commutative”. For the specific construction of cyclic algebras $\bigoplus_{j=0}^{n-1} Lu^j$ for a cyclic Galois extension $L/K$ of degree $n$, we have $\alpha{u} = u\sigma(\alpha)$ for all $\alpha \in L$, where $\sigma$ is a choice of generator of ${\rm Gal}(L/K)$. Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: So y'all are thinking that a field is a skew field the way a group is a quasi-group.  I'm okay with that, I guess... it certainly makes more sense.  The point Peter made, about skew symmetry/commutativity is exactly what irked me.  I would be a lot happier if skew fields were *only* the non-commutative division rings.